# How can I upgrade my Xamarin.iOS version from 9.6.1.8 to 9.6.1.9 in windows machine?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

How can I upgrade my Xamarin.iOS version from 9.6.1.8 to  9.6.1.9 in windows machine?

I have already checked for updates in Xamarin Studio and also checked for updates in Visual Studio 2015>Tools>Options>Xamarin>Other>Check Now and all is looking up to date but as the error log says, Xamarin.iOS version is supposed to be  9.6.1.9.

Thanks in advance.

> Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.LogHandler Warning: 0 : [2016-04-05
>   16:13:04.2398] There is a mismatch between the installed Xamarin.iOS
>   (version 9.6.1.9) on the Mac MacMiniBuildServer.local (192.168.101.15)
>   and the local Xamarin.iOS 9.6.1.8. While this may not be an issue, it
>   might cause unexpected behaviors. When applying updates, make sure to
>   keep both the Mac and Windows in sync.

Comment: It is important to note that this is merely a warning (and as the message indicates, it may not be an issue) and does not block any functionality of the tooling. There is often a minor difference between PC/Mac versions for X.iOS. Putting this in the comments so folks in the future will see this information quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with Apple Store Distribution Certificate.

I followed [this steps](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment%2C_testing%2C_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/) and after recreating the Distribution Certificate, all problem was sorted out, so didn't need to upgrade my Xamarin.iOS version to 9.6.1.9.

Hope this might be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 3):

When updating Xamarin

- ensure that the same release channel (stable, beta, alpha) is used on both machines (visible on the update dialog of each tool).

On Mac

- Open Xamarin Studio Open `Xamarin Studio > Check for Updates`
- Download updates
- Press Restart & Install Updates

On Windows

- Open Xamarin Studio `Help > Check for Updates`
- Download updates
- Press Restart & Install Updates
- Open Visual Studio `Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other > Check now`

To be **damn** sure, close and restart everything :P

If it still appears: see the answer from BytesGuy

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I mentioned in my question, I have already tried that, when I check for updates, the message is "Up to date".

Comment: The Xamarin Studio on Windows?

Comment: i'm really glad MS bought them. 30% of the time i'm trying to get xamarin to work/compile again after an update. and android is getting System.Serialization exception 75% of the time when deploying

Comment: @Dbl It's alot better than 3 years ago ;) We were restarting Visual Studio after each Debug Session. I know 3 types of iOS buildhosts ^^ They made progress and now they have more manpower :)

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe i can't even imagine the sheer nightmare that must have been. It's an impressive product for sure - but in terms of deployment+debugging quality i'm certainly looking forward to the upcomming future :)

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe thanks for your detailed answer, I have tried all those steps before asking this question. I can debug my ios application on both simulator and iphone but the problem is when I try to create the IPA by following [this documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/ipa_support/#Creating_an_IPA), it is failing and giving that warning message. Any more ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is often a discrepancy in the minor version for Xamarin.iOS between the PC and Mac.

This message can be safely ignored as long as you are on the latest stable version on both you PC and Mac (which you seem to be).

The only time this can become an actual issue is when your major versions are different (e.g., 9.6 on PC and 9.8 on Mac).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think you are right but because of this problem I can't create my IPA. [This is the documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/ipa_support/#Creating_an_IPA) that I am following to create my IPA and I believe this version difference is causing the problem as there isn't another warning or error message in the Xamarin logs. Btw I can debug in a simulator or an iphone, so do you have any ideas how I can create my IPA? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole 9.6 vs. 9.8 is my issue I can't seem to resolve, have you found the solution?