# Where can I get details or Release Notes of Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.13?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Today, January 28, 2019 around 11:00 AM(UTC+9), I updated my Mac and Windows' Xamarin development environment to latest version.
But versions of Xamarin.iOS are different between Mac and Windows.(below)

[Windows]

-Visual Studio Enterprise 15.9.6

-Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   12.2.1.12

[Mac]

-Visual Studio Enterprise for Mac 7.7.3

-Xamarin.iOS Version 12.2.1.13

-XCode 10.1(10B61)

[Question]

Where can I get details or Release Notes of  Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.13 ?

[Information]

1. I cannot find Release notes of Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.13
   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/12/12.2)
2. There are few results searching "Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.13" by Google.
   (https://www.google.com/search?q=Xamarin.iOS+12.2.1.13)
3. Versions of Xamarin.iOS are different (12.2.1.12 and 12.2.1.13) but I can deploy my App to iOS Devices.
4. "Check for updates..." screen of Visual studio for mac shows below before updating.

   [Image of Check for Updates...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkJHJ.png)
5. Details of Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.13 says "Fore more information, please see release notes here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/12/12.2, but nothing mentioned about Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.13 there.

Comment: Are you sure `12.2.1.13` is the Xamarin.iOS version that you have in your system? Because I am only aware of a `12.2.1.12` version release.

Comment: Thank you for replying.

I checked non-updated visual studio for mac again.
(I am sorry. I should check this before question.)

I'm updated my question and add capture of updates screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk5DT.png

Comment: Are you sure this is the stable channel?

Comment: Yes. I am sure this is the stable channel.

"更新チャネル:安定" of the capture means "Update Channel : Stable"

Comment: I am Sorry for not considerate.
I replaced my Capture Japanese to English.I confirmed it's surely shown on stable channel(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkJHJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found related question below and understood that different minor versions of Xamarin.iOS between Mac and Windows is not that weird.

[Dominic(Work for Xamarin) answered "There is often a minor difference between PC/Mac versions for X.iOS." in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432025/how-can-i-upgrade-my-xamarin-ios-version-from-9-6-1-8-to-9-6-1-9-in-windows-mach)

So my worry about different minor versions between Mac and Windows is disappeared.

I still wonder why there is no release notes but I feel it's not important.

Hakim san,

Bruno san,

Thank you for your time about my question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found, it is available in the latest version of Visual Studio for Mac

```
Visual Studio for Mac 7.7.3.43 comes with:

Mono Framework MDK 5.16.0.221
Xamarin.Android 9.1.5-1
Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.13
Xamarin.Mac 5.2.1.13
Xamarin.Profiler 1.6.4-33
Xamarin Inspector 1.4.3
Xamarin Interactive 1.5.0
NuGet 4.3.1.4445
dotNET SDK 2.1.302
```

You can check those release notes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-mac-relnotes#7.7.3)

Comment: Thank you for replying and information.

I still wonder why the version of Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.13 only mentioned in updates screen of visual studio for Mac(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk5DT.png)  while the version of Xamarin.iOS on the latest version of Visual Studio (Windows) is 12.2.1.12 ?

Also, there seems to be no release notes of Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.13 on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/12/12.2

I think versions of Xamarin.iOS should be same between mac's and windows' when I deploy iOS app from windows' Visual Studio.

Do I misunderstand something ?

Comment: The thing is, you are using the preview updates in visual studio, so you have acess to features that are not "stable" or released. That's why they won't show up in the normal release notes. You need to wait until they are public.

Comment: Thank you for replying.

I am Sorry for confusing.I replaced my capture Japanese to English.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkJHJ.png).

And I surely confirmed Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1.13 shown on Stable Channel.

Something strange phenomenons are happened on my Mac PC?